# determinant of 3 points in java

Tags: java

I am creating a java application. I need to calculate the determinant of three point. I have calculated it:

```
     static int determinant(Point point1, Point point2, Point point3) {
    int x1 = point1.x;
    int x2 = point2.x;
    int x3 = point3.x;
    int y1 = point1.y;
    int y2 = point2.y;
    int y3 = point3.y;
    return (x1 * y2) + (x3 * y1) + (x2 * y3) - (x3 * y2) - (x2 * y1)
            - (x1 * y3);
}
```

(I am not good in math)But, I found the following when I searched about it:

```
public int ccw(int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
return (xPoints[p2] - xPoints[p1])*(yPoints[p3] - yPoints[p1]) - (yPoints[p2] -    yPoints[p1])*(xPoints[p3] - xPoints[p1]);
}
```

which one is the correct method? If the first method is the correct one, what does the second method do?

Comment: Are you sure you want determinant? What are you trying to accomplish?  Traditionally, the determinant is not defined for a non-square matrix (which you have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both equations are the same.  there is no mathematical difference between the two.

someone better at math than I could probably give you the mathematic proof.  I chose to go the practical route, implemented in python, because I can

```
def fun1(p1,p2,p3) :
   print (p1[0]*p2[1])+(p3[0]*p1[1])+(p2[0]*p3[1]) - (p3[0]*p2[1]) - (p2[0]*
   p1[1]) - (p1[0]*p3[1])

def fun2(p1,p2,p3) :
   print (p2[0]-p1[0])*(p3[1]-p1[1])-(p2[1] - p1[1])*(p3[0]-p1[0])

>>> fun1((0,0),(9,1),(3,2))
15
>>> fun2((0,0),(9,1),(3,2))
15
>>> fun2((33,5),(4,6),(8,1))
141
>>> fun1((33,5),(4,6),(8,1))
141
```

for any 3 points, fun1 and fun2 will yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The second version assumes that the points are defined in two one-dimensional arrays:

```
int [] xPoints;
int [] yPoints;
```

- `xPoints[p]` holds the x position of point p
- `yPoints[p]` holds the y position of point p

I haven't done the math, but perhaps the two methods actually calculate the same thing.